# how to make android menu icon and menu items larger

Tags: java, android, xml

I made a menu.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_credits"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="About-Credits"/>

</menu>
```

and I added that in my toolbar, like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

and this is how it looks:

[image]

How do I make the menu icon and menu items a little bit larger and also vertically centered in the toolbar?

Comment: I want to understand do you want menu item to be placed over toolbar ?

Comment: i want the menu icon(the one with the 3 dots) to be larger and vertically centered in the toolbar. I have made a custom toolbar with more height than the default thats why it doest fit properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set icon by adding this line of code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_credits"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="About-Credits"
    android:icon="drawable/icon name/>
```

Comment: app:showAsAction="always" is required for showing it on toolbar

Answer (score 0):

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/about_credits"
            android:title="About-Credits"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_menu_item" />   
    </menu>
```